# What is Chino's age in Naruto Shippuuden?

Tags: naruto

Chino, the character from the arc that starts at episode 484 of Naruto Shippuuden, is said to be

> older than Sasuke in spite of looking like a child

Does she have a known age? If not, what would be her estimated age range?

This is the character I'm referring to http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chino

Answer (score -2):

It was mentioned that Chino was a few thousand years old, about the same age as Gamamaru.

Comment: Do you have a source or reference to back this up?